# Store multiple values in an array and show it in the tabular form

Tags: angular, angular6

I have pushed multiple value into the array named MyArrayType in component.ts file but want to display it into the tabular form in component.html file. Is their a way by which I can store it into variable or some kind of data-binding?

```
if(this.disableEveryday == false){
  this.MyArrayType.push(
     this.everydayAllFromValue,
     this.everydayBreakfastFromValue,
     this.everydayDinnerFromValue,
     this.everydayLunchFromValue)
}
else{
  this.MyArrayType.push(
      this.mondayAllFromValue,
      this.mondayBreakfastFromValue,
      this.mondayDinnerFromValue,
      this.mondayLunchFromValue,
      this.tuesdayAllFromValue,
      this.tuesdayBreakfastFromValue,
      this.tuesdayDinnerFromValue,
      this.tuesdayLunchFromValue,
      this.wednesdayAllFromValue,
      this.wednesdayBreakfastFromValue,
      this.wednesdayDinnerFromValue,
      this.wednesdayLunchFromValue,
      this.thrusdayAllFromValue,
      this.thrusdayBreakfastFromValue,
      this.thrusdayLunchFromValue,
      this.thrusdayDinnerFromValue,
      this.fridayAllFromValue,
      this.fridayBreakfastFromValue,
      this.fridayLunchFromValue,
      this.fridayDinnerFromValue,
      this.saturdayAllFromValue,
      this.saturdayBreakfastFromValue,
      this.saturdayLunchFromValue,
      this.saturdayDinnerFromValue,
      this.sundayAllFromValue,
      this.sundayBreakfastFromValue,
      this.sundayLunchFromValue,
      this.sundayDinnerFromValue)
}
```

Comment: Note that AngularJs is the name of the version 1, for version 2 and above, please use "Angular" tag only (I removed the tag). Good luck with your question

Comment: new to angular, sorry, removed

Comment: @Screech Whats stopping you from showing in tabular format. Can you share your `html` code where you have tried it

Comment: i have no idea, how to display it. It is displaying it as a whole data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's quite hard to interpret you issue but this is the code to show data in tabular form -

```
   <table>
        <tbody *ngFor="let element of MyArrayType; let j=index">
            <tr>
              <td>{{element}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use *ngFor loop ex:

```
<table>
    <tbody *ngFor="let data of MyArrayType; let j=index">
        <tr>
          <td>{{data}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

here ( MyArrayType ) it is your array name

if your data ( MyArrayType ) is object type like

```
[{"name":"Ram", "email":"Ram@gmail.com"},  
{"name":"Bob", "email":"bob32@gmail.com"}]
```

than use it like:

```
<table>
<tbody *ngFor="let data of MyArrayType; let j=index">
    <tr>
      <td>{{data.name}}</td>
      <td>{{data.email}}</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody></table>
```

i hope it is helpful for you....!